# How can I write a formula in javascript and use html to show the formula and display the results?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a simple formula of:

Force = pressure x area = (resluts showign here)

I think I have the formula correct, but how do I go about displaying the results?

The code I have so far is this below:

```js
    <body>
    <h1> 
    Force = 
    <input type="number" id= "pressure" value= ""/> x  <br/>
    <input type= "number" id= "area" value= ""/>
    <button onclick = "equals" id="equals" >=</button>
    <output type="number" id= "forceResult" ></output> 
    </h1>
    </body>
    
    let pressure = document.getElementById (pressure);
    let area = document.getElementById (area);
    let equals = document.getElementById (equals);
    let forceResult = document.getElmentById (forceResult);
    
    function force1 (pressure, area) {
    let force = pressure * area;
    return force;
    }
    equals.onclick () => {
     force.innerHTML = force 
    }
    
    }
```

```html
    <h1> 
    Force = 
    <input type="number" id= "pressure" value= ""/> x  <br/>
    <input type= "number" id= "area" value= ""/>
    <button onclick = "equals" id="equals" >=</button>
    <output type="number" id= "forceResult" ></output> 
    </h1>
```

Comment: In the click handler. you need to retrieve the form field values, do the math (which you can do by calling your function), and putting the results into the output contents. Which part/s cause/s issues?

Comment: You should put labels on the fields for accessibility purposes.

Comment: What is the issue with your code? Please [edit] your post. You have syntax errors. Use [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of assigning to an `onclick` property. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: @DaveNewton  Which part/s cause/s issues?  I am cllicking on the button "equals" and I get nothing... I changed the .onclick to:

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains a lot of errors and typos. Write it more carefully

```js
let pressure = document.getElementById('pressure');
let area = document.getElementById('area');
let equals = document.getElementById('equals');
let forceResult = document.getElementById('forceResult');

function force1 (pressure, area) {
  return pressure * area;
}

equals.onclick = function () {
    const pressureValue = Number(pressure.value)
  const areaValue = Number(area.value)
    const result = force1(pressureValue, areaValue)
  
  forceResult.innerHTML = result
}
```

```html
<h1> 
  Force = 
  <input type="number" id="pressure" value=""/>
  x<br/>
  <input type="number" id="area" value=""/>
  <button onclick="equals()" id="equals">=</button>
  <output type="number" id="forceResult"></output> 
</h1>
```

Comment: thank  you much...  I'll be watching much more Udemy videos...